# While Deleting Repeated Headers

Tags: excel, vba

Using the below code to delete the repeated headers from combined into one excel but getting error.

```
  Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

   ' AutoFit the column width in the summary sheet.
   DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

   With Application
       .ScreenUpdating = True
       .EnableEvents = True
   End With
   
   Dim xWs As Worksheet
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       If xWs.Name <> "Combined Sheet" Then
           xWs.Delete
       End If
   Next
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   
   Dim lstRow As Integer, ws As Worksheet
       Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined Sheet")
       With ws
       lstRow = .Cells(rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row ' Or "C" or "A" depends

       .Range("A1:E" & lstRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete   ERROR GETTING HERE

   End With
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDqQd.png)

Comment: What does it do and what is it supposed to do? Please explain what the *"repeating headers"* in your screenshot actually are. Note that you talk about deleting headers yet in your code you are trying to delete entire rows if any of the cells in each row range of a range is empty (not blank).  Please clarify. You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72317935/edit) at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add "on error resume next" before using SpecialCells method and after using use "on error GoTo 0"

Answer (score 0):

```
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
```

This expression gives you every blank cell in a Range. Rows that you are going to delete includes non-blank cells also, so vba will not delete them.
You can try a RemoveDuplicates method like:

```
    .Range("A1:E" & lstRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Header :=xlNo
```

It can be not safe to use the method, but for your task it's may be Ok.

This sub is a safe variant to delete your headers. you can call the sub by the Call statement, and don't forget to set your header address.

```
    Call removeHeaders()

    Sub removeHeaders()
    Dim hdrRangeAdr As String
    Dim l, frstRow, lstRow, offsetRow As Long
    Dim counter, row1, row2 As Integer
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim hdrRng, tRng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
        
        ' setting of the first header address
        hdrRangeAdr = "A1:O1"
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined Sheet")
        ' setting of the header range
        Set hdrRng = ws.Range(hdrRangeAdr)
        hdrRowsQty = hdrRng.Rows.Count
        frstRow = hdrRng.Row
        lstRow = hdrRng.Parent.UsedRange.Rows.Count + frstRow
        
        'checking row by row
        For l = 1 To lstRow - frstRow
            offsetRow = l + hdrRowsQty - 1
            counter = 0
            ' compare row/rows value with the header
            For Each item In hdrRng.Cells
                If item = item.Offset(offsetRow, 0) Then
                    counter = counter + 1
                End If
            Next
            
            ' if they are equial then delete rows
            If counter = hdrRng.Count Then
                row1 = frstRow + offsetRow
                row2 = row1 + hdrRowsQty - 1
                ws.Rows(row1 & ":" & row2).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                'reseting values as rows qty reduced
                l = 1
                lstRow = hdrRng.Parent.UsedRange.Rows.Count + frstRow
            End If
        Next
        
        Set ws = Nothing
        Set hdrRng = Nothing
        
    End Sub
```

Good luck

Comment: hey thanks for helping out and for your answer but can you rewrite the provided code and check the excel attached once so that will try your code worked or not for me.

Comment: then attach the file (sample)

Comment: you can check the image of sample file attached already with the question also tried using your code but it throws the error "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet failed"